# mod_rewrite and .htaccess 404ing in a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

For example:

**Dir structure**

```
localhost/
 |- test/
    |- index.php
    |- .htaccess
```

**index.php**:

```
 <?php
        if(isset($_GET['cmd'])){
            echo "cmd is ok";
        }
 ?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /test/index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

---

If user sets: `http://localhost/test/index.php?cmd=a`

Output will be: `cmd is ok`

That is ok!

**I want to get same result if user** sets `http://localhost/test/a`

**How should .htaccess/mod_rewrite be set ?**

With code up there, I just get 404.

Comment: I'm struggling for hours, simply don't get it. Please help me.

Comment: You might get a better response if you try asking on serverfault.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Might be smart to add the option of a trailing slash: `RewriteRule ^test/(.+)/?$ /test/index.php?cmd=$1 [L]`

Comment: @SpoonNZ - Correct. There might even be more stuff after that trailing slash. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the trailing forward slash here:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /test/index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

Remove that or make it optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /test/index.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

Else it won't match the url that ends with just `.../a`

Comment: With `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /test/index.php?cmd=$1 [L]` i got still 404. With `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /test/index.php?cmd=$1 [L]` - Internal Server Error 500. Why ???

Comment: You have to look into the `error.log` then for the actual error 500 reason. Also set up a `RewriteLog` (difficult) if it constantly runs wrong. You might need a `RewriteBase` or something.